# Volume Activation issues

Tags: windows

Prior to my taking over as a sysadmin the previous had switched volume activation to a new server. I opened the VAMT to check on things today and saw that the 'date of last license status update as ~1/22/2015 for most active systems and nothing newer than that.

I have little experience with Volume Activation but have done the following:
*DNS shows a CNAME record for kms.domain.com to a server which has Volume Activation Services installed. The services appear to be running (all which are automatic at least, I'm not sure if there are others to check)

It looks like we are using KMS and not active directory-based authentication as I can 'view configuration' from the VAT tool installed on the server. It shows DNS, activation for Domain/Private networks, port 1688, and 'volume activation interval hours (2) volume license renewal days (7)

How can I troubleshoot and find out why VAMT shows no activation occurring?

```
C:\>cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /dlv all
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Software licensing service version: 6.3.9600.17809

Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
Activation ID: 00091344-1ea4-4f37-b789-01750ba6988c
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Extended PID:
Product Key Channel:
Installation ID:
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: 997
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:33 AM
Configured Activation Type: All
Please use slmgr.vbs /ato to activate and update KMS client information in order
 to update values.


Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, OEM_COA_NSLP channel
Activation ID: 1226e046-263d-414c-824f-0d4f458cee3a
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Extended PID:
Product Key Channel:
Installation ID:
Use License URL: https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLAct
ivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: -1
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:34 AM


Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, OEM_COA_NSLP channel
Activation ID: 1cc95b8e-1b6e-42cc-9768-9e84ce28cc3f
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Extended PID:
Product Key Channel:
Installation ID:
Use License URL: https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLAct
ivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: -1
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:34 AM


Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, VOLUME_KMS_2012-R2_WIN10 channel
Activation ID: 20e938bb-df44-45ee-bde1-4e4fe7477f37
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Extended PID:
Product Key Channel:
Installation ID:
Use License URL: https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLAct
ivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: -1
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:34 AM

Key Management Service is enabled on this machine
    Current count: 50
    Listening on Port: 1688
    DNS publishing enabled
    KMS priority: Normal

Key Management Service cumulative requests received from clients
    Total requests received: 5546
    Failed requests received: 670
    Requests with License Status Unlicensed: 0
    Requests with License Status Licensed: 2793
    Requests with License Status Initial grace period: 1981
    Requests with License Status License expired or Hardware out of tolerance: 3

    Requests with License Status Non-genuine grace period: 0
    Requests with License Status Notification: 99


Name: Office 15, OfficeKMSHostVL_KMS_Host edition
Description: Office 15, VOLUME_KMS channel
Activation ID: 2e28138a-847f-42bc-9752-61b03fff33cd
Application ID: 0ff1ce15-a989-479d-af46-f275c6370663
Product Key Channel: Volume:CSVLK
Use License URL: https://activation.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLActiva
teProduct.asmx?configextension=o14
Validation URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=187557
License Status: Licensed
Remaining App rearm count: -1
Remaining SKU rearm count: -1
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:34 AM

Key Management Service is enabled on this machine
    Current count: 10
    Listening on Port: 1688
    DNS publishing enabled
    KMS priority: Normal

Key Management Service cumulative requests received from clients
    Total requests received: 1016
    Failed requests received: 10
    Requests with License Status Unlicensed: 0
    Requests with License Status Licensed: 942
    Requests with License Status Initial grace period: 60
    Requests with License Status License expired or Hardware out of tolerance: 0

    Requests with License Status Non-genuine grace period: 0
    Requests with License Status Notification: 4


Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, VIRTUAL_MACHINE_ACTIVATION channel
Activation ID: 640e7014-6f45-4106-bd1d-ac17a812a2d1
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Extended PID:
Product Key Channel:
Installation ID:
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: -1
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:34 AM
Guest IAID: {49c27749-4629-45d5-ad53-2b4a4f85b8c5}


Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, VOLUME_MAK channel
Activation ID: 641f81b2-63c2-47dd-aba7-c24bf651ff85
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Extended PID:
Product Key Channel:
Installation ID:
Use License URL: https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLAct
ivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: 1001
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:34 AM


Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, OEM_SLP channel
Activation ID: 66d129b6-eae9-414e-a39a-ea5b8be961cc
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Extended PID:
Product Key Channel:
Installation ID:
Use License URL: https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLAct
ivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: -1
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:34 AM


Name: Windows(R), APPXLOB-Server add-on for ServerStandard,ServerStandardEval,Se
rverDatacenter,ServerDatacenterEval,ServerStorageWorkgroup,ServerStorageWorkgrou
pEval,ServerStorageStandard,ServerStorageStandardEval,ServerSolution,ServerWinFo
undation,ServerHyperCore,ServerCloudStorage
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, VOLUME_MAK channel
Activation ID: 9d0bb49b-21a1-4354-9981-ec5dd9393961
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Extended PID:
Product Key Channel:
Installation ID:
Use License URL: https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLAct
ivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: -1
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:34 AM


Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, VOLUME_KMS_2012-R2_WIN10 channel
Activation ID: 9e3fde40-d4b3-4c1d-9bde-32735aa19b39
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Extended PID:
Product Key Channel:
Installation ID:
Use License URL: https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLAct
ivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: -1
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:35 AM

Key Management Service is enabled on this machine
    Current count: 50
    Listening on Port: 1688
    DNS publishing enabled
    KMS priority: Normal

Key Management Service cumulative requests received from clients
    Total requests received: 5546
    Failed requests received: 670
    Requests with License Status Unlicensed: 0
    Requests with License Status Licensed: 2793
    Requests with License Status Initial grace period: 1981
    Requests with License Status License expired or Hardware out of tolerance: 3

    Requests with License Status Non-genuine grace period: 0
    Requests with License Status Notification: 99


Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, VOLUME_KMS_WS12_R2 channel
Activation ID: acf1b4fd-1c55-4f2d-a60b-415ac958ad88
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Extended PID:
Product Key Channel:
Installation ID:
Use License URL: https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLAct
ivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: -1
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:35 AM

Key Management Service is enabled on this machine
    Current count: 50
    Listening on Port: 1688
    DNS publishing enabled
    KMS priority: Normal

Key Management Service cumulative requests received from clients
    Total requests received: 5546
    Failed requests received: 670
    Requests with License Status Unlicensed: 0
    Requests with License Status Licensed: 2793
    Requests with License Status Initial grace period: 1981
    Requests with License Status License expired or Hardware out of tolerance: 3

    Requests with License Status Non-genuine grace period: 0
    Requests with License Status Notification: 99


Name: Microsoft Office 2010, KMSHost edition
Description: Microsoft Office 2010 KMS, VOLUME_KMS channel
Activation ID: bfe7a195-4f8f-4f0b-a622-cf13c7d16864
Application ID: 59a52881-a989-479d-af46-f275c6370663
Product Key Channel: Volume:CSVLK
Processor Certificate URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88342
Machine Certificate URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88343
Use License URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88345
Product Key Certificate URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88344
License Status: Licensed
Remaining App rearm count: -1
Remaining SKU rearm count: -1
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:35 AM

Key Management Service is enabled on this machine
    Current count: 10
    Listening on Port: 1688
    DNS publishing enabled
    KMS priority: Normal

Key Management Service cumulative requests received from clients
    Total requests received: 6970
    Failed requests received: 29
    Requests with License Status Unlicensed: 0
    Requests with License Status Licensed: 1728
    Requests with License Status Initial grace period: 5198
    Requests with License Status License expired or Hardware out of tolerance: 9

    Requests with License Status Non-genuine grace period: 0
    Requests with License Status Notification: 6


Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, RETAIL channel
Activation ID: c2d61e88-5598-4e77-aae2-286dc6670a89
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Extended PID:
Product Key Channel:
Installation ID:
Use License URL: https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLAct
ivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: -1
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:35 AM


Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, VOLUME_KMS_WS12_R2 channel
Activation ID: dcb88f6f-b090-405b-850e-dabcccf3693f
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Product Key Channel: Volume:CSVLK
Use License URL: https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLAct
ivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
License Status: Licensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: 1001
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:35 AM

Key Management Service is enabled on this machine
    Current count: 50
    Listening on Port: 1688
    DNS publishing enabled
    KMS priority: Normal

Key Management Service cumulative requests received from clients
    Total requests received: 5546
    Failed requests received: 670
    Requests with License Status Unlicensed: 0
    Requests with License Status Licensed: 2793
    Requests with License Status Initial grace period: 1981
    Requests with License Status License expired or Hardware out of tolerance: 3

    Requests with License Status Non-genuine grace period: 0
    Requests with License Status Notification: 99


Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, OEM_SLP channel
Activation ID: fecbc8f2-a4b1-402a-92e7-5d81a6fe3e80
Application ID: 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Extended PID:
Product Key Channel:
Installation ID:
Use License URL: https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLAct
ivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 996
Remaining SKU rearm count: -1
Trusted time: 9/18/2015 11:38:35 AM
```

Comment: VAMT is just an *audit* tool, it is not the service actually performing the activation. It needs RPC connections to all systems you want audited. Do you need VAMT running again or are you troubleshooting a KMS issue?

Comment: Well, I have received two messages now - one that the kms server didn't have enough clients to run from a computer which should've been authenticated (and was back in January). I ran slmgr /rearm and it seems to have fixed the issue after a reboot. I also ran that command on a machine which reported it wasn't activated and may be counterfeited. It rebooted and seems okay now. I've looked more and will run slmgr /dli next time to get additional info. I'd like the VAMT tool to be up to date as well, but verifying KMS activations are working is more critical. @the-wabbit Thanks!!!

Comment: The output of `slmgr /dlv all` on the KMS server should help checking if the KMS server has valid keys and is receiving requests. Is this your only KMS server?

Comment: slmgr /dlv shows that the server is activated, slmgr /dlv all gives a window that is bigger than the screen and I can't see all of it, I do see at least one unlicensed field though. @the-wabbit

Comment: when running `cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /dlv all` you will get the output into the command line window instead of a GUI message box. Could you copy / paste that into your question? It is rather normal to see "unlicensed" for certain products in the list, but obviously it is crucial that the ones your clients are requesting for activation are not in unlicensed state.

Comment: Should I filter out the 'Application ID and Activation IDs'? Also the Extended PID / Installation ID or anything else? We've got about 363 lines so I think I'll put it to pastebin or something after you reply. @the-wabbit

Comment: Just clean out the installation ID, extended PID and the partial product key - the rest should be safe. You also can just paste it into your question marking it as *code* - it will render as an inline box with scroll bars.

Comment: @the-wabbit Sorry for the delay. I have updated the question with the requested information. For lines that had an Installation ID or Extended PID I have removed that line, all others were just empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you are trying to activate OS products you have not entered a product key for.

Office 15 seems to activate rather okay, I have stripped the less important parts of the `/dlv` output here:

```
Name: Office 15, OfficeKMSHostVL_KMS_Host edition
Description: Office 15, VOLUME_KMS channel
[...]
License Status: Licensed
[...]
    Total requests received: 1016
    Failed requests received: 10
```

Upon entering of the product key a product's license status is changing to "Licensed". You also should see "Total requests received" increase without the "Failed requests received" increasing.

Your OS activation seems to have a problem as the number of the "failed requests" is rather high. Also, you seem to have the Windows 10 KMS update installed, but no key entered for it:

```
Name: Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, VOLUME_KMS_2012-R2_WIN10 channel
[...]
License Status: Unlicensed
[...]
    Total requests received: 5546
    Failed requests received: 670
```

You should [obtain the *Windows Srv 2012R2 DataCtr/Std KMS for Windows 10* key from the Microsoft VLSC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3086418) and use `slmgr /ipk <productkey>` to install it on your KMS server. Afterwards, check if the license status in the *VOLUME_KMS_2012-R2_WIN10* product section (it should change to "Licensed") and track the number of requests received / failed to see if client activation is successful.

When trying to do further debugging, keep in mind that it is rather difficult to get meaningful activation diagnosis from the KMS service itself. A more promising approach would involve running slmgr /ato on the clients and trying to resolve the error code returned by the activation call.